# Error 1904 - Module ‘acropdf.dll’ failed to register. HRESULT -2147024769. Contact your support personnel

Tags: adobe, installshield

I have developed Install shield package. in that i have a exe which depends on acrobat.dll. when i install it throw a above error. please give a solution. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that you are including acrobat.dll in your install package? If so then remove that file and include Adobe's installer as a prerequisite for your application. We cannot distribute third party files unless the third party company grants permission. If you have such an agreement with a third party company then they should provide you with information for redistributing their files.